# Cufflinks: how to set upper and lower value for the colorscale?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, heatmap, plotly

Let's say that I have a DataFrame which contains a Cufflinks heatmap (like [this one](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/#Heatmaps)).

Normally, I plot it in the following way. Notice that I specified a preset colorscale by the name 'spectral'.

```
heatmap.iplot(kind='heatmap', title='title', colorscale='spectral', xTitle='xTitle', yTitle='yTitle')
```

It shows me a heatmap, but the value range of the colorscale (not the color, but the min/max values the colorscale is mapped to) is auto-decided.

I want to be able to specify the min/max value so that the coldest color maps to the min value, and the hottest color maps to the max value. My use case is that I have multiple color maps to compare to each other, and I need them to have the same value<->colorscale mapping so that the value difference across these heatmaps are obvious from the colors.

BTW, I don't want to manually specify all the color mappings inside the colorscale, since that means I need to first dig out how the colorscale 'spectral' maps which values to what colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: You can't do it directly with `cufflinks` because `zmin` and `zmax` are no keyword arguments.

The long answer: Transforming your DataFrame is simple but getting the same color scale as `cufflinks` is a bit trickier (isn't it fun when two identically named colorscales have different mappings?)

```
df.iplot(kind='heatmap')
```

is identical to

```
plotly.offline.iplot([go.Heatmap(z=df.transpose().values)])
```

So now we can set the upper and lower range of the `colorscale` via `zmin` and `zmax`

```
plotly.offline.iplot([go.Heatmap(z=df.transpose().values, zmin=0, zmax=40)])
```

Now let's extract the colorscale from `cufflinks` and feed it to our heatmap

```
scale = cf.get_scales()['spectral']
l = len(scale) - 1
spectral = [[i / l, s] for i, s in enumerate(scale)]

plotly.offline.iplot([go.Heatmap(z=df.transpose().values, 
    zmin=0, 
    zmax=40, 
    colorscale=spectral
)])
```

The complete code

```
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import plotly.graph_objs as go

cf.go_offline()
df = cf.datagen.heatmap(20,20)
df.iplot(kind='heatmap', colorscale='spectral')

scale = cf.get_scales()['spectral']
l = len(scale) - 1
spectral = [[i / l, s] for i, s in enumerate(scale)]

plotly.offline.iplot([go.Heatmap(z=df.transpose().values, zmin=0, zmax=40, colorscale=spectral)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the time to write this step-by-step guides the thought process which is very helpful. I love that you put the short answer in front then followed by detailed reasoning and an alternative which I believe is quite good. Thanks man!